# MySQL How to have a summary column (Y/N) based on values in other column

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table called Cats:

`Cats`

```
  id colour  spots  weight
  -- -----   -----  ------
  1  brown   Yes    7
  2  black   No     9
  3  white   No     13
  4  orange  Yes    11
  5  grey    No     20
  6  yellow  Yes    17
```

How do I make it so I have another column that tells me "if the cat's weight is **above 10**, it will be considered overweight" demonstrated with a **binary 1**. And of course, "if the cat's weight is **under 9**, it's considered not overweight" **demonstrated with 0**. So it will sort of look like this:

```
  id colour  spots  weight  overweight
  -- -----   -----  ------  ----------
  1  brown   Yes    7       0
  2  black   No     9       0
  3  white   No     13      1
  4  orange  Yes    11      1
  5  grey    No     20      1
  6  yellow  Yes    17      1
```

I just want to use a select statement that will summarize this rather than inserting a new column and inputting the overweight 1/0 myself. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *,  
        (weight > 10) overweight
FROM    Cat
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f557/2)

In MySQL, `(weight > 10)` is a boolean arithmetic which returns `1` or `0` as a result.

Comment: I didn't even know that's possible without using case when statements.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt but it works on Mysql only though. To be more RDBMS friendly, use `CASE`.